# Can I use 'will' twice in this sentence?

Tags: conditional-constructions, future-tense

Is it correct to use will twice in the following sentence?

> Will your books will be available in electronic format?

Comment: Why? What's wrong with *Will your books be available in electronic format?*

Comment: Have you seen any reference work which approves of such a usage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you convert a statement into a question in English, you swap the subject and the auxiliary verb. Here is a statement:

> Your books **will** be available in electronic format.

In this statement, **your books** is the subject and **will** is the auxiliary verb. You swap them to make a question, thus:

> **Will** your books be available in electronic format?

In your sentence, you have not swapped the subject and auxiliary- you have simply added another **will**. I understand why you think the second **will** is necessary in that position (it was in that position in the statement), but the swapping is what makes it into a question, so you can't simply add another one.

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not correct. The future tense uses the word "will" only once; you cannot use it twice.